# Bandwidth control for my home network

Tags: networking, bandwidth, internet

Goodday, I just wanna ask if how can i control the bandwidth of the wiFi users. I have two routers. First is the modem/wireless router (DHCP) (2in1) (KASDA brand) provided by my ISP, it has other configuration except for bandwidth control. The second router is Tenda W316R and it has bandwidth control feature. This is what i want to achieve, i want the second router (Tenda) to be my home access point to use it for bandwidth control while still using the first router provided by the ISP. Can you help me about the configuration of the two routers? Thanks you :)

Comment: Why not use the Tenda as the entire network router? Makes the router of the Kesda redundant, yes, but you'll get what you want for your entire network?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the full capabilities of your router, but, First you cannot use 2 routers using DHCP on the same network.
I would disable the DHCP on your Modem/Router, and just use it as your Modem, and Gateway to your second DHCP Router. You can then set your Bandwidth controls, and possibly create different groups with different bandwidth limitations if the Router has this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what is the configuration should i do with the first and second router, like Default Gateway etc. Thank you.

Comment: @Ralph, Your Kasda Modem/ Router should be switched to Gateway, with DHCP, and Wireless functions disabled. In this mode it will just serve as your Modem for internet, and a Gateway for your Tenda Router. The default Gateway settings for the Kasda should work, keep in mind that the default IP Address of the Kasda is 192.168.1.1, The Tenda Router may use that same IP Address, so you may have to manually issue a static IP for the Tenda, probably 192.168.1.2, although the Kasda may automattically issue a new IP for the Tenda to prevent IP conflicts. Now set up the Tenda as your DHCP Router.